# Does Apache Lucene support approsimate string matching?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, string-matching

Does Lucene support approximate (fuzzy) string pattern matching?
If so, how does it do that? I couldn't find out reading the APIs.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly supported:  [FuzzyQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html).  Not quite sure what you mean when you ask "How does it do that?"  Are you just looking for how to use a FuzzyQuery, or what algorithm lucene uses for fuzzy querying, or what?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @femtoRgon. And yes, I mean the algorithm it uses and then how to use it :)